# Initializing string array for data reference

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do with this is save a list of reference keys for everything that is populating a listbox. There will be an unknown quantity of lines(users/"patients"). After saving the list, I want to be able to use the listbox index to find the corresponding key, and use that to move on to the next part.

```
public partial class PatientList : Window
{
    HumanResources ListAllPatients;
    List<PatientInformation> AllPatients;
    string[] Usernames;

    public PatientList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int i = 0;
        string[] Usernames = new string[i];
        ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
        AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();

        foreach (PatientInformation PatientChoice in AllPatients)
        {
            Usernames[i] = PatientChoice.Username;
            lboxPatients.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}; {2}", PatientChoice.FirstName, PatientChoice.LastName, PatientChoice.Gender));
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the button that moves you on to the next section

```
public void btnSelectPatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PatientInfo PatientInfoWindow = new PatientInfo();
        PatientInfoWindow.Show();
        //i = lboxPatients.SelectedIndex;
        //UserFactory.CurrentUser = Usernames2[i];
        this.Close();
    }
```

My issue is this: I believe I've initialized a string array to do this, but VS keeps telling me it isn't assigned to, and will always remain null.

My question: How and where do I properly initialize a string array (or something better) in order to accomplish sending the key from PatientList() to btnSelectPatient?

Comment: Where do you initialize it?

Comment: I believe I've initialized it at the very top, right after List<PatientInformation> AllPatients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *not* initializing the `string[]` field but a local variable in the constructor here:

```
string[] Usernames;

public PatientList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int i = 0;
    string[] Usernames = new string[i];
```

You have to assign this array to the field:

```
public PatientList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int i = 0;
    this.Usernames = new string[i];
```

But that doesn't make much sense currently because it's length is always 0.

Maybe you  want this instead:

```
public PatientList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
    AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();
    this.Usernames = new string[AllPatients.Count];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (PatientInformation PatientChoice in AllPatients)
    {
        Usernames[i] = PatientChoice.Username;
        lboxPatients.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}; {2}", PatientChoice.FirstName, PatientChoice.LastName, PatientChoice.Gender));
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that last little bit was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes:

- Your initializing a new local variable instead of the class-level variable because you declare it again (`string[] userNames = ...`
- Your initializing an array of length 0. This will fail when you try to add items to position 1 and above.

My advice would be to use a List, as it's better suited for dynamic length lists and you don't need to keep track of the index yourself, it will automatically be added at the right index:

```
HumanResources ListAllPatients;
List<PatientInformation> AllPatients;
List<string> Usernames = new List<string>();

public PatientList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListAllPatients = new HumanResources();
    AllPatients = ListAllPatients.PopPatientList();

    foreach (PatientInformation PatientChoice in AllPatients)
    {
        Usernames.Add(PatientChoice.Username);
        lboxPatients.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}; {2}", PatientChoice.FirstName, PatientChoice.LastName, PatientChoice.Gender));
    }
}
```